# How to handle a NetworkCacheImage from a Future<String> Url without making it load whenever the state changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

**so simply i wanted to fetch a profile picture with an unknown path with this simple code**

```dart
    Future<String> getProfilePicUrl(email) async {
      String bucket = 'gnospace-a727c.appspot.com';
      String directory = '$email/profilePic';
    
      try {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    
        Reference directoryRef = storage.ref().child(directory);
    
        ListResult result = await directoryRef.listAll();
    
        List<String> downloadUrls = [];
        for (var item in result.items) {
          String downloadUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
          downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
        }
    
        return downloadUrls[0];
      } catch (e) {
        return 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gnospace-a727c.appspot.com/o/Default%20Profile%20Picture.jpg?alt=media&token=1ee3ce93-64c4-4ad3-960a-ac66de4710d8';
      }
    }
```

it should return the url of the file inside the storage of my database

then i wanted to take that url which is now Future

and put it inside a CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: getProfilePicUrl(email))

but the problem here CachedNetworkImage wants only String , n`ot Future String

and when i solved it with a future builder , the image starts reloading again whenever a state change on the page

Here is the code of the specific block

```dart
    Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                        child: FutureBuilder<String>(
                          future: futurepeople,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return const Icon(Icons.person, size: 100);
                            } else {
                              return CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: snapshot.data!,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                const Icon(Icons.person, size: 100),
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

I was trying to get images from my firebase storage with dynamic URLs and make it get saved in the phone's cache and if that link ever changed, the image would automatically change when i refresh the page

---

i don't want it to just keep refreshing whenever any state change on the same page (only want it to refresh when the picture is updated)

---

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `cacheKey`, `maxHeightDiskCache`, and `maxWidthDiskCache`.

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
        key: key,
        maxHeightDiskCache: 1000,
        maxWidthDiskCache: 500,
        cacheKey: ApiKeys.baseUrl + imageUrl,
      ),
```

Comment: I think the error i am facing is not because of the CachedNetworkImage but the future builder.. , i have to use it because the String is FutureString but yet, when the state change , it makes all the picture provided by that code turn to a CircularProgressIndicator()
in my case, it is a chat page. so everytime someone sends a message, all pictures suddenly turn to CircularProgressIndicator and then get back in 2 seconds or less

Comment: If you use any state management like bloc, provider, etc. your problem will be fixed because you will trigger events just one...   But for now try to make List<String> downloadUrls  as public "put it outside the method" and at the beginning of the getProfilePicUrl method check if the list is not empty, return it with index 0.